# node streams - get maximum call stack exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, callstack

I cant seem to figure out why I'm getting this error with my stream pipeline.  I think I have exhausted all paths, so is there something Im missing: Here is what I have:

```
var myCsvStream = fs.createReadStream('csv_files/myCSVFile.csv');
var csv = require('fast-csv');
var myData = [];

var myFuncs = { 
 parseCsvFile: function (filepath) {

  var csvStream;

  csvStream = csv
  .parse({headers: true, objectMode: true, trim: true})
  .on('data', function (data) {

       myData.push(data);

  })
  .on('end', function () {

    console.log('done parsing counties')
  });

  return csvStream;

 }
}

myCsvStream
.pipe(myFuncs.parseCsvFile())
.pipe(process.stdout);
```

The `process.stdout` is just so I can see that the data can continue on to the next stream, however, when adding `pipe(process.stdout)` or even a `through2` duplex stream I get this maximum callstack reached error.  Any Ideas?

Comment: How large is your CSV file? Also, is the code you're showing the exact code that you're using?

Comment: The csv file completes its parsing, so I know its not a size issue, but for information sake its around 2.8MB.  And no this isnt exact code.  I left out some requires and other code not associated with issue

Comment: But are you getting the same error with the code you posted (I've run a 70MB file through it just fine)? Otherwise it's kinda hard to guess what's going on. There aren't any potentially recursive calls in your code, and I don't think `fast-csv` is the issue either.

Comment: `/Users/tpoher/projects/blah/myproj/node_modules/fast-csv/lib/parser/parser_stream.js:287
    emit: function (event) {
                   ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
` is the error Im getting , so maybe it is 'fast-csv', but I dont see how or why.  Also, are you not getting this error when you run the code above?

Comment: @robertklep It appears its an issue with `fast-csv`, as I just changed libraries to use `csv-streamify` and this works `myCsvStream.pipe(parser).pipe(process.stdout)` when using the `csv-steamify` parser stream. Filling out issue ticket with them now

Comment: Issue ticket for fast-csv if anyone is interested: https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv/issues/103

Comment: Interesting. Like I said, I used (almost) the same code to parse a 70MB CSV file and that works just fine. The code you posted here, and in the Github issue, isn't completely functional though (`myData` is undefined and piping to `process.stdout` in object mode doesn't work).

Comment: @robertklep i left out the definition of myData because I thought it could be assumed as defined and initialized as an empty array `var myData =[]`, however, I can see the confusion.  I wonder why its working for you.  Can you show me what you have because I get the above listed error when I run it.

Comment: Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/6083d5a06d4b03059a24) of my testing code (using `fast-csv@0.6.0`). The CSV file I'm testing on has about 500K lines (70MB file size), and it's running okay.

Comment: @robertklep comment left in gist

Comment: likewise :-) (GH doesn't support mentions in Gist comments...)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write it that way :

```
var myCsvStream = fs.createReadStream('csv_files/myCSVFile.csv');
var csv = require('fast-csv');

var csvStream = csv
  .parse({headers: true, objectMode: true, trim: true})
  .on('data', function (data) {
    myData.push(data);
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    console.log('done parsing counties')
  });

myCsvStream
.pipe(csvStream)
.pipe(process.stdout);
```

After you can wrap it all up in a function.

Comment: I still get same error taking the csvstream out into its own variable then calling that like the way you suggested.  Can you not run the stream through a pipe when using listeners like `on('data'...)`?